# Can polynomial be a solution to linear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Can polynomial
\begin{equation}
\pi_x(t) = \sum^m_{k=0}x_kt^k
\end{equation}
be a solution to  a linear ordinary differential equation:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x}(t) = A x(t)
\end{equation}
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Comment: The general solution is $\vec x=e^{At}\vec x_0$. If I'm not mistaken, this function is a polynomial in $t$ iff $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: As a caveat to my previous comment, $\vec x(t)$ is polynomial in $t$ *for all initial conditions* iff $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Furthermore I think it is true that $\vec x(t)$ is a polynomial iff $A^k\vec x_0=\vec 0$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally won't work if $A \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ is a constant matrix, since, writing

$x(t) = \sum_0^m x_i t^i, \tag 1$

where the $x_i \in \Bbb R^n$, we have

$\deg Ax(t) = \deg x(t) = m; \tag 2$

but

$\deg \dot x(t) \le m - 1. \tag 3$

There are however certain classes of matrices for which polynomial solutions may be had, e.g. if $A$ is nilpotent, as pointed out in the comment of Kajelad.  But there will never be a solution when $A$ is non-singular, since it will then not annihilate $x_m$, the coefficient of $t^m$.

I may return to this later and discuss conditions on $A$ which imply the existence of a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Trivially, the general solution of $$\frac{d^{m+1}}{dt^{m+1}}y(t)=0$$ is any polynomial of degree $\le m$. And we can certainly write that as a first order differential equation for the vector $\langle y,\dot{y},\ldots\rangle$, with constant coefficients.

Comment: In the accepted answer I got information when it is possible and when it is not that the solution of ordinary differential equation is a polynomial. This tells me how I can fit a polynomial to ordinary differential equation. I am not sure whether I was clear about that in the question. Nevertheless, I really appreciate this question, thank you.

Comment: You are requiring $m$ to be a whole number, though. It might be also interesting to consider a function $f(x)=x^a$ where a is a real number, and fig-out what differential equation has this solution form.